# Generation of triples from text for KG

Tags: python, triples, structured-text, knowledge-graph

I am trying to process documented text and extract triples data from the text to build a graph. I have used the stanford nlp module for generating triples, it gives good results. I want to generate domain specific triples and process the text data. I am looking for any papers, modules or any other implementation for generation triples from text.

Any help is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago I used [FRED](http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/), which is available both as a REST service and as a standalone Python library. The only issue I had was that the REST service did not scale that well.